# Ionic 4 unable to display data inside ngFor

Tags: ionic4, angular8

I am trying to fetch payment methods from razorpay payment gateway. But unable to display it. The problem is there is no data available at the time of display. How do I wait for data to load? 
Thank you in advance 
.ts

```
  banks : [];

    constructor() {

        this.razorpay = new Razorpay({
          key : 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
          key_secret: 'XXXXXXXX'
        })

        this.razorpay.once('ready', function(response) {
          this.banks = response.methods.netbanking
          console.log(this.banks)
          this.display = true

        })

       }
```

html

```
<ul *ngIf="display">
  <li *ngFor="let hero of banks | async">
    {{ hero }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

[image]

Comment: do you get an error?

Comment: No. Not getting any error

Comment: did you initialized `banks` to an empty array, like `banks = []` ? Have you tried `<ul *ngIf="display">` ?

Comment: Yes. I have tried both of them

Comment: Could you check the value of "display" and the length of banks by printing them?

Comment: I have uploaded an image. The value of "display" is true and a list of banks[]

Comment: Ok, try to move that code inside the ngOnInit method, rather than the constructor

Comment: I tried it. But still can't display data on page

Answer (score 1):

As your result  `console.log(this.banks)` is in key value pair.

Your keys are `AUBL,ABPB,AIRP,ALLA`

You can bind data like this

```
<ul *ngIf="display">
<li *ngFor="let hero of banks | async">
{{ hero.AUBL }}
{{hero.ABPB}}
//so on
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

With the [KeyValuePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe) you will be able to iterate over the properties of the object. Remove the async pipe, as you're not working with an observable.

```
<ul *ngIf="display">
    <li *ngFor="let hero of banks | keyvalue">
        {{ hero.key }}: {{ hero.value }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

And initialize the banks object correctly as an object instead of an array.

```
banks = {};
```

This will give a result like

- AUBL: AU Small Finance Bank
- ABPB: Aditya Birla Idea Payments Bank
- ...

Comment: You use the async pipe and don't have an observable. I changed my answer to correct that problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the API returns Object rather that an Iterable such as Array.
if you need to display each property of such object you would have to transform the object to an array:

```
constructor() {
    this.banks = [];

    this.razorpay = new Razorpay({
      key : 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
      key_secret: 'XXXXXXXX'
    })

    this.razorpay.once('ready', (response) => {
      let methodsObj = response.methods.netbanking
      this.banks = Object.entries(methodsObj)
      console.log(this.banks)
    })

  }
```

Then your template is:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let hero of banks">
    {{ hero[0] }}, {{ hero[1] }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Still not able to display data. Strange problem though

Comment: so based on your own answer, was the issue for your just the use of fat arrow function?

Answer (score 0):

```
this.razorpay.once('ready', (response) => {

      this.banks = response.methods.netbanking
      console.log(this.banks)
      this.display= true
      console.log(this.display)
    })
```

I have to use arrow **(response) =>** as a callback. By using **function()** you can't bind object data